# datatemplate listbox selected item

Tags: wpf

here's my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Search"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Search" Height="600" Width="1024">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="listBoxTemplate" xmlns:ns="clr-namespace:MyConverters">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <ns:ImageConverter x:Key="MyImageConverter" />
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=thumb, StringFormat=/WpfTest;component/Images/{0}, Converter={StaticResource MyImageConverter}}" Height="100" Width="130" Margin="5"></Image>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="247">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding recipeName}" Height="60" Padding="15" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding cuisine}" Height="60" Padding="15" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="12,96,0,0" Name="lstSearchResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="704" Height="445" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables[0]}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" SelectionChanged="lstSearchResult_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,49,0,0" Name="txtSearchRecipe" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518" FontSize="16" />
        <Button Content="Search" Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="555,49,0,0" Name="btnSearchRecipe" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" Click="btnSearchRecipe_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

now i want to open a new form based on the item I clicked on the listbox, passing the new form the data from the selected item's textblock. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly you don't need to do anything special to access the TextBlock controls in the DataTemplate.  You just need to take advantage of your bindings by adding a SelectedItem binding using TwoWay binding to your ListBox.

If you're using MVVM, I would suggest you map a Command on your button click event to your View Model passing the SelectedItem as the command parameter.  Then, in the command handler, cast the SelectedItem to the type you expect (this should be the type of object in the collection you've bound to your ListBox ItemsSource).  You can then send the properties bound to the TextBlocks to the view model of your new window.  If setup propertly these items should exist in your SelectedItem.  Then set the window's DataContext to the corresponding window viewmodel and show it.

If you're just using code behind, simply cast the SelectedItem to the type used in the ListBox ItemsSource collection.  Then pass the properties bound to the TextBlocks to the new window.  Then show the window.

Comment: i'm not using MVVM.. what do you mean by "simply cast the SelectedItem to the type used in the ListBox ItemsSource collection. Then pass the properties bound to the TextBlocks to the new window."

Comment: i just use the method here http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7 and now it work. anyway I'll accept your answer as the right one because technically it's right, although it's too basic too my liking ;)

Comment: If you bind your SelectedItem into an object located in the code behind, you can then access the properties bound to the textblocks in your DataTemplate.

Your ListBox ItemsSource collection is bound to a generic collection.  The type used in that generic collection would be the type for the SelectedItem.  So if you're using an ObservableCollection<MyObjectType> and you bind your ListBox SelectedItem to an object of type MyObjectType named MySelectedItem, when you handle the click, you can case the SelectedItem to MyObjectType.  The result would have the members recipeName and cuisine in it.